Linuxserver/Codeserver for vuejs development
I'm using Linuxserver/codeserver (https://hub.docker.com/r/linuxserver/code-server) as Dockerimage on my Synology for development. Right now I'm trying to get access to my vuejs app. It starts on port 5173, and I can "reach" it via the proxy url. The problem is, I cant see a thing! I reach the codeserver via an nginxproxy, but also used the direct IP from my Syno, I created a new vue project to be sure that mine is not broken but always the same white screen...
In Mozilla I get this informations:
I also tried to open the port on the synology, I also tried some configs on the nginx. After testing the IP connection, I'm sure that there is another problem.
Can someone help me or give me a hint , at what I should look?
Best regards!
Reaching via proxy, reaching via ip, changed proxy conf, opening ports, new vue project

Do you have a server running there to serve you the app? Even if it is just an SPA you still need some sort of server to run it. If you upload your code on the server, try to SSH on it and run a npm dev (or alike). Then you can reach out the local IP address to move forward. Vite should even give it to you. Also I am not sure of your firewall settings but you might not even need to open a port possibly.

You can also try with something simple first: access a static asset (like an image) on the same directory as your Vue project.

You can use VSCode remotly inside the container. I start the app with yarn run dev and vite starts and gives me the URL. The Image creates an proxy URL so that you can reach your apps and apis outside of the container. As an example :
http://localhost:5173/ is the Vite url for local development, so If you would use it on an native machine , you could use the url to use and test the app. Now the image takes it an do something like: {serverip}:{port}/proxy/{appip} -> 192.168.x.y:8080/proxy/5173 <- this should normaly return the app but just gives the error shown above

I get the idea. So only the proxy doesn't work? The regular server on the Synology is accessible from your other machine? I just want to make sure that the server is properly working by itself (to remove any possible points of failure). Also have you checked their GH for potential similar issues?

The proxy worked for Rest endpoints written with quarkus. Only the proxy for the vuejs app doesnt work. And Yes I can connect to it an work on it :). I checked the GH and didnt find anything
